Browsershot and puppeteer running correctly in dev mac server, but not in ubuntu production
I successfully installed and used Browsershot, puppeteer and chrome in my Mac M1 homebrew, but stuck with an error in production server, which is running Ubuntu 22.
this is the code I used to generate a dynamic image:

        Browsershot::url( url('posts/share-image-preview', $id) )
            ->windowSize(1080, 1080)
            ->setIncludePath('$PATH:/usr/bin/npm')
            ->save('images/share/'.$id.'.png');

        return url('images/share/'.$id.'.png');

Problem:
The command "PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/npm NODE_PATH=`npm root -g` node 
'/home/example.com/website/vendor/spatie/browsershot/src/../bin/browser.cjs' 
'{"url":"https:\/\/example.com\/posts\/share-image-preview\/641","action":"screenshot","options":{"type":"png","path":"images\/share\/641.png","args":[],
"viewport":{"width":1080,"height":1080}}}'" failed. 
Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: /home/example.com/website/public 
Output: ================ Error Output: ================ 
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 125.0.6422.60). This can occur if either 
1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npx puppeteer browsers install chrome`) or 
2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/example.com/.cache/puppeteer). 
For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration. at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:295:27) at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:209:25) at ChromeLauncher.computeLaunchArguments (/usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:89:37) at async ChromeLauncher.launch (/usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ProductLauncher.js:70:28) at async callChrome (/home/example.com/website/vendor/spatie/browsershot/bin/browser.cjs:91:23)

Trying to solve this problem, these are the things I did:

As the error message suggests, I created a writable cache directory. .cache
installed npx puppeteer browsers install chrome
I checked my npm installation with whereis npm and it returns /usr/bin/npm. So the setIncludePath is correct.
The public path public/images/share/ is writable.
installed puppeteer globally npm install puppeteer --location=global

Is there something I'm missing?
Update:
The server was running npn as root, that created a permission problem. Reinstalled node and npm as the user the webserver is running.
However, I'm stuck with this error:
For some reason Chrome did not write a file at `images/share/641.png`. Command ======= {"url":"https:\/\/example.com\/posts\/share-image-preview\/641","action":"screenshot","options":{"type":"png","path":"images\/share\/641.png","args":[],"viewport":{"width":1080,"height":1080}}} Output ======

Here's what I tried, but problem persists:

Looked for compatible puppeteer version for my specific node version.

Suggestions, hints and help are welcome.
